# How can I put the table caption on the top in pdfLaTeX?

Tags: tables, positioning, captions

I have this code

```
\begin{table}[H]
  \caption{My Caption }
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{*{6}{|p{3cm}}}
  \hline\hline
```

But caption comes at bottom.

I can't use this

```
\begin{table}[Ht]
```

as it gives error.

Comment: Please complement your code to a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example, but as [doncherry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4012/doncherry) says, provide a MWE if this is not what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[tableposition = top]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \centering
  \caption{A caption.}
  \label{table:triathlon}
  \begin{tabular}{l *{2}{S[table-format = 3]}}
   \toprule
             & {Triathlon}     & {Ironman}       \\
             & {\si{\percent}} & {\si{\percent}} \\
   \midrule
    Swimming &   3             &   2             \\
    Cycling  &  50             &  80             \\
    Running  &  47             &  19             \\
   \midrule
    Total    & 100             & 101             \\   
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

This is table~\ref{table:triathlon}.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]